# Computing the norm of a linear functional using Lebesgue decomposition and the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

The following question comes from the textbook *Functional Analysis, Spectral Theory, and Applications* by Einsiedler & Ward, which I am currently studying.

**Problem:** Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two finite Borel measures on a locally compact metric space $X$. **Compute the norm of the functional** $F: C_c(X) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $$F(f) := \int f \ d\mu - \int f \ d\nu$$ and $C_c(X)$ denotes the space of all functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support equipped with the infinity-norm $||f||_{\infty} := \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$.

**Remarks:** The author suggests one makes use of the following previously established facts (we can take these as assumptions to make):

1. If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on a locally compact $\sigma$-compact metric space $X$, and $g \in L_\mu^1(X)$, then the norm of the functional on $C_0(X)$ defined by $$g \ d\mu : C_0(X) \ni f \mapsto \int fg \ d\mu$$ is precisely $||g||_{L_\mu^1}$.
2. The Lebesgue decomposition & Radon-Nikodym theorems have already been established.

**Attempt:**
We first write the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$, so that $$\nu = \nu_a + \nu_s,$$ where $\nu_a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, and $\nu_s$ and $\mu$ are singular with respect to each other. Since $\nu_s \perp \mu$, let $X = X_\mu \sqcup X_{\nu_s}$ (disjoint union), where $$\nu_s(X_\mu) = \mu(X_{\nu_s}) = 0.$$ Moreover, we'll let $\varphi$ denote the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu_a$ with respect to $\mu$. I.e., $\varphi := \frac{d \nu_a}{d \mu}$. One has, $$\int f \ d\mu - \int f \ d\nu = \int f \ d\mu - \int f \ d\nu_a - \int f \ d\nu_s = \int f \ d\mu - \int f \varphi \ d\mu - \int f \ d\nu_s$$ which then reduces to $$F(f) = \int (1 - \varphi) f \ d\mu - \int f \ d\nu_s.$$ From Remark (1), I would like to apply that result to the integral on the left when it comes time to compute the norm. However, I am stuck on how to deal with $\int f \ d\nu_s$. Any hints that make use of the remarks would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to clarify that you are using the infinity norm on $C_c(X)$. This is standard, but it is worth saying explicitly for those who are new to these ideas.

You have that $\nu_s\perp\mu$, so basically you are adding two linear functionals with disjoint support. That is, you have
$$
F=F_{1-\varphi}+F_s,
$$
where
$$
F_{1-\varphi}(f)=\int_X(1-\varphi)f\,d\mu,\qquad\qquad F_s(f)=-\int_Xf\,d\nu_s.
$$
You already know the norm of the first functional. For the second, the usual estimate
$$
|F_s(f)|\leq\|f\|_\infty\,\nu_s(X)
$$
together with an appropriate choice of $f$, say $f=1_X$, show that $\|F_s\|=\nu_s(X)$.

In general the norm of the sum of two functionals is not the sum of the norms. But here the two functionals have disjoint supports. So if $g\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is such that $\|g\|_\infty=1$ and $\int_X(1-\varphi)g\,d\mu=\|1-\varphi\|_1$ and we let
$$
h=g-1_{X_s},
$$
the following happens. The fact that the domains are disjoint guarantees that $$\|h\|_\infty=\max\{\|g\|_\infty,\|1_{X_s}\|_\infty\}=1.$$
And
$$
F(h)=\|1-\varphi\|_1+\nu_s(X). 
$$
It is easy to see that this is also an upper bound, so
$$
\|F\|=\|1-\varphi\|_1+\nu_s(X).
$$
The above $g$ might not exist, but one can get approximations up to an $\varepsilon$, and adjust the above argument accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. An additional question: Is there another textbook where this exercise appears? Your quick response makes me wonder if this same problem has shown up in other textbooks, and it would be nice to know if that's the case.

Comment: Can't tell. First time I see something like this. But it is kind of obvious if one is familiar enough with Measure Theory and Functional Analysis.